# How to fetch records form three table

Tags: sql

Table  Name :: Feedback_master

Fields
1. feed_id
2. roll_id
3. batch_id
4. sem_id (semester ID)
5.f_id (faculty Id)
6. sub_id (subject Id)
7. remark.
8. b_id

Table Name :: subject_master

Fields

1. sub_id (subject Id)
2. sub_name (Subject Name0
3. f_id ( Faculty ID)

Table Name :: faculty_master

Fields

1. f_id (Faculty Id)
2. f_name (Faculty Name)
3. l_name (Faculty Name)
4. b_id

This are the three tables.  Now I want to fetch the detail from this three table.

I want the output as

f_Name (faculty name), Sub_name (Subject Name ) , remark (Remark )

could some one help me to over come this problem.

Answer (score 1):

something like...

```
select fm.remark, sm.sub_name, fcm.f_name from Feedback_master fm
left join subject_master as sm  On fm.sub_id = sm.sub_id
left join faculty_master as fcm On fcm.f_id = sm.f_id
```